# Custom permalink with pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, permalinks, pagination, query-variable

I have a custom post type called **news** and in order to distinguish *current* and *old* news posts I have a custom field where the client can mark a news post as '*archived*'.

So my permalink rewrite code looks like this:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/archive/?','index.php?post_type=news‌​&news_archive=true',‌​'top'); 
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/archive/page/([0-9]+)?/?$','index.php?post_type=news&news_archive=true&paged=$matches[1]','top');   
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "news_archive";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

The first bit works but the problem is with the pagination. I can access the ***news_archive*** query_var but not the ***paged*** query_var.

What is the correct way to incorporate paged into this permalink rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your first rule is capturing anything that begins with `news/archive/`.

Add the `$` anchor to match *only* `news/archive/`:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^news/archive/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=news&news_archive=true',
    'top'
);
```

Your pagination rule will then begin to work as-is after you flush permalinks.